# Why my two test case failed for given Regex Pattern

Tags: java, regex, xss

**When i run testcase program, my two str29 and str32 testcase failed, so i need regex pattern which can success all test cases.**

*My Test Class given Below     :*

```
package com.csam.wsc.enabling.core.util.test;

import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class RegularExTest {

    private static Pattern xssAttackPattern;
        // this pattern for whilte list character 
    private static final String XSS_ATTACK_REGULAR_EXPRESSION = "([A-Za-z0-9,()[\\\\]{}\\\":./_\\\\s]|(?<!-)-)*";

    public static void main(String arg[]) {
        testSQLOrXSSInjectionAsWhiteListApproach();
    }

    private static Pattern getXSSAttackPattern() {
        xssAttackPattern = Pattern.compile(XSS_ATTACK_REGULAR_EXPRESSION);
        return xssAttackPattern;
    }

    public static boolean hasXSSAttackOrSQLInjection(String value) {
        if (getXSSAttackPattern().matcher(value).matches())
            return false;
        return true;
    }

    public static void testSQLOrXSSInjectionAsWhiteListApproach() {

        String str0 = "";
        String str1 = ",:4,5}{A{,}1{}r,'ee4534:r,p],[A},{1}}{A{,}345:,";
        String str2 = "a";
        String str3 = "A#";
        String str4 = "#";
        String str5 = "#'";
        String str6 = "123";
        String str7 = "As";
        String str8 = "{#}";
        String str9 = "#{}";
        String str10 = "!";
        String str11 = "'124";
        String str12 = "123'";
        String str13 = "'";
        String str14 = "''";
        String str15 = "Hello";
        String str16 = "<>";
        String str17 = "<>/?\":;";
        String str18 = "!@#$%^&*()_+}{|\":<>?,./[]\\";
        String str19 = "Good";
        String str20 = "A\\%27";
        String str21 = ".";
        String str22 = "/";
        String str23 = "_";
        String str24 = ".'";
        String str25 = "/_";
        String str26 = "_.";
        String str27 = "http://rss.cnn.com/rss/edition_business.rss";
        String str28 = "http://rss.cnn.com/rss/edition_business.rss?id=121132511$@#$@$@#%242444+gfghgfhg";
        String str29 = "Communication in progress...";
        String str30 = "(";
        String str31 = ")";
        String str32 = "(.:[]{} ";
        String str33 = "(.:[]{} #";
        String str34 = "&";
        String str35 = "$";
        String str36 = "-dsfdsfddsfd2112212s";
        String str37 = "--dsfdsfddsfd2112212s";
        String str38 = "-dsfdsfdd-sfd2112212s";
        String str39 = "--";
        String str40 = "-";


        assertFalse(str0);
        assertTrue(str1);
        assertFalse(str2);
        assertTrue(str3);
        assertTrue(str4);
        assertTrue(str5);
        assertFalse(str6);
        assertFalse(str7);
        assertTrue(str8);
        assertTrue(str9);
        assertTrue(str10);
        assertTrue(str11);
        assertTrue(str12);
        assertTrue(str13);
        assertTrue(str14);
        assertFalse(str15);
        assertTrue(str16);
        assertTrue(str17);
        assertTrue(str18);
        assertFalse(str19);
        assertTrue(str20);
        assertFalse(str21);
        assertFalse(str22);
        assertFalse(str23);
        assertTrue(str24);
        assertFalse(str25);
        assertFalse(str26);
        assertFalse(str27);
        assertTrue(str28);
        assertFalse(str29);
        assertFalse(str30);
        assertFalse(str31);
        assertFalse(str32);
        assertTrue(str33);
        assertTrue(str34);
        assertTrue(str35);
        assertFalse(str36);
        assertTrue(str37);
        assertFalse(str38);
        assertTrue(str39);
        assertFalse(str40);


    }

    public static void assertFalse(String value) {
        boolean result = hasXSSAttackOrSQLInjection(value);
        String var = "undefined";
        if (result == false) {
            var = "success";
        } else {
            var = "fail";
        }
        System.out.println("For given string -> " + value + " -> " + var);
    }

    public static void assertTrue(String value) {
        boolean result = hasXSSAttackOrSQLInjection(value);
        String var = "undefined";
        if (result == true) {
            var = "success";
        } else {
            var = "fail";
        }
        System.out.println("For given string -> " + value + " -> " + var);
    }
}
```

Comment: **regex pattern in code for white list character, means those character should allowed.**

Answer (score 0):

Here's your regex as a string literal:

```
"([A-Za-z0-9,()[\\\\]{}\\\":./_\\\\s]|(?<!-)-)*"
```

The real regex is:

```
([A-Za-z0-9,()[\\]{}\":./_\\s]|(?<!-)-)*
```

I see two major problems here.

1. Unlike most flavors, Java allows you to embed a character class in another character class.  Your regex does not match square brackets (`[` or `]`) because the `[\\]` is interpreted as an embedded character class that matches a backslash.
2. `\\\\s` in the string literal becomes `\\s` in  the regex.  You probably meant that to be `\s`, the class shorthand for a whitespace character, but it's really a literal backslash followed by `s`.

You need to escape the square brackets and fix the escaping of the `\s`.  This regex matches all your sample strings:

```
([A-Za-z0-9,()\[\]{}":./_\s\\]|(?<!-)-)*
```

When I create a character class with a literal backslash in it, I like to put the backslash last.  I find it a little easier to read that way, and if I mess things up, it's more likely to throw an exception than to silently match the wrong thing.

Note also that the quotation mark (`"`) doesn't need to be escaped for the regex parser, only for the Java parser.  That means you only need one backslash in the string literal, not three.  Here's the final, string literal form of your regex:

```
"([A-Za-z0-9,()\\[\\]{}\":./_\\s\\\\]|(?<!-)-)*"
```